# Stumped on this little SQL query

Tags: sql, search, autocomplete, wildcard

This SQL query is currently returning all values with the word anywhere in it. For instance, typing Mon will return Armoring, Behemoth, Emotion, etc etc. I'd like it to return words that start with the value, like, Monkey, Moment, Monday, etc.

Hope my explanation makes sense, code is below.

```
    function action_ajax_drug_suggest() {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $_GET['term'] ) ) {
        die();
    }

    $drug_name = $wpdb->esc_like( $_GET['term'] );

    $table = $wpdb->prefix . self::TABLE_DRUG;

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
                SELECT name
                FROM {$table}
                WHERE name LIKE '%%%s%%'
                    AND details <> ''
                LIMIT 5",
            $drug_name ) );


    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $names[] = array(
            'label' => $post->name,
        );
    }

    wp_send_json( $names );

}
```

Comment: So remove the leading `%%` from the `LIKE`.

Comment: Have tried that, I get a null response.

Answer (score 0):

try leaving out the first two %% signs
*LIKE '%%%s%%'* becomes *LIKE '%s%%'*

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, but this one isn't working. Makes sense as to why it would, but that was one of the first things I tried.